# SQL - Oracle - Duplicate IDs with more than one Customer Name value into a separate column

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

Please help me determine a "good" or best way of setting up this query, of course, if it will work. = )

Below is an example and basic query that provides CustomerID, Cust Name, UserName and Email.  I'm trying to take the multiple username/email fields for one CustID and placing them in a new/separate field so that I have a distinct CustomerID.

An example of the current data is:

```
Cust_Nbr   Cust_Name   User_Name   Email
0011       Customer11  User1a      Email1a
0011       Customer11  User1b      Email1b
```

Trying to achieve:

```
Cust_Nbr   Cust_Name   User_Name   Email     UserName2  Email2
0011       Customer11  User1a      Email1a   User1b     Email1b
```

The sql is similar to this:

```
SELECT
 cust.CUST_ID,
 cust.CUST_NAME,
 orders.NAME Orders_Name1,
 orders.EMAIL EMAIL1
FROM
 CUSTOMER cust,
 ORDERS_USERS orders,
 SALES_TRANS sls
WHERE
 etc...
GROUP BY
 etc...
```

I tried devising a way to do a union copying the select statement 3x and then trying to separate the values with new alias column names, e.g., username1, username2, etc., but that didn't work very well.

Any suggestions?  Should I use a count statement with an indicator and then group those as sub selects?  Not too sure.

Also, I am familiar with SQL Server format, but please keep in mind this is Oracle sql. Thanks!

Comment: Are you guaranteed that you will have at most two rows?  Or might you have three or more rows with the same `cust_nbr`?  If you had  three rows, would you want two additional columns?  You can do that but then you've got to resort to dynamically building the SQL statement.  If you are guaranteed at most two rows, do you care which row goes in which column?  If so, what determines which row is `UserName` and which is `UserName2`.

Comment: If a single customer could have multiple user_names, then rather than splitting them out into separate columns, far better would be to normalise the tables by splitting the `customer table` into two, having `cust_nbr` and `cust_name` (along with any other columns you may have that belong at the customer level, rather than the user_name level) in one table and `cust_nbr`, `user_name` and `user_email` in another. Then you could add a foreign key from the 2nd table back to the first based on `cust_nbr`.

Comment: Great questions! My bad for not clarifying...  Yes, there could be some that are distinct, but some could be more. I initially planned on having at the most 4 emails, but I haven't verified.  Yes, it would be considered a dynamic query.  I do not care which goes into which column - any order is fine.

Comment: I am at the mercy of the tables and structures that I have to work with.  I'm having to use the tables and joining them as I have them now based on the information that is stored in each.  I don't believe that at the time this scenario would have come up or else they would have made the user information easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't good solution, but if you have known rows you may use:

```
with tb (Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name,User_Name,Email) as (
    select '0011', 'Customer11', 'User1a', 'Email1a' from dual union all
    select '0011', 'Customer11', 'User1b', 'Email1b' from dual)
select Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name,
       max(decode(user_rn,1,User_Name)) as User1,
       max(decode(user_rn,2,User_Name)) as User2,
       max(decode(email_rn,1,User_Name)) as Email1,
       max(decode(email_rn,2,User_Name)) as Email2
from
  (select Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name,User_Name,Email,
          row_number() over (partition by Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name order by User_Name) as user_rn,
          row_number() over (partition by Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name order by Email) as email_rn
   from tb)
group by Cust_Nbr,Cust_Name
```

Comment: In a strange way, this seems to have worked; although, I shouldn't be surprised because using row_number has always been a tremendous help.  I just need to expand this to allow up to 5 users/emails, and I take it you meant to have the Email column in the decode instead of User_name, correct?  I believe so, because it appears to be doing what it should when I change it. Thanks again!  I had to use this as an option because the listagg was not working with our current setup in Toad. But I'm marking both as answered! = )

Comment: Well, one caveat is that now I'm getting dupes for each of the customers that do have username/email values being that they are outer joined to the sales table so that I get all customers regardless if there are usernames/emails associated. I later realized I hadn't include the join information. I'm trying a solution; however, any suggestions in the meantime?  Below is an example of the tables and joins:
 FROM
  CUSTOMER cust,
  ORDERS_USERS orders,
  SALES_TRANS sls
 WHERE
  sls.CUST_ID = cust.CUST_ID
   AND sls.BRANCH = cust.CUST_BRANCH
   AND orderuser.ID(+) = sls.ORDERS_USERID

Comment: It's placing a 1 for the rownumber for the ones that do have values in the orderusers table, but putting the 1 for the dupe row without the values.  If that makes sense. So, where there are values for username/email, then it starts at 2 instead of 1. it appears to be using 1 for the customer table

Comment: Correction: not all records with usernames/emails start with rownumber 1. So, if I can devise a way to get the value of the rownumber for the ones that are coming from the orderusers table first or be able to order them somehow, I think I can work this out.  Maybe there's a different solution?

Comment: Hi. If I understood you correctly, you get duplicated values after join and have equal values in columns emal1, user1 and emal2, user2. Am I right? If it's your problem change row_number() to dense_rank().

Comment: Actually, I'm getting dupe CustomerID, CustomerNames where the username/email data is on one line and the Customer data is on another.  It dupes for each one that has a record in the usersorders table.  Let me see if I can demonstrate below:
BRANCH CUST_NBR CUST_NAME Orders_Name1 EMAIL1 Orders_Name2 EMAIL2

Comment: BRANCH CUST_NBR CUST_NAME Orders_Name1 EMAIL1 Orders_Name2 EMAIL2
002   0011   Customer11   username11  email11
002   0011   Customer11   (these columns are blank on the dupe row)

Comment: Yep, I had a couple of columns from the orders table that were causing the dupe rows.  Appears to be fine now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

first of all i would strongly recommend you to redesign your table(s) and split the data into two tables "customer" and "email" (customer_id, ...) - this will make your life much easier. But if you can't change it here is an answer:

```
create table customer(id int, name varchar2(100), username varchar2(100), email varchar2(100));

insert into customer
select 1,'Customer11', 'User1a', 'Email1a@mail.com' from dual
union
select 1,'Customer11', 'User1b', 'Email1b@mail.com' from dual
union
select 1,'Customer11', 'User1c', 'Email1c@mail.com' from dual
union
select 2,'Customer12', 'User12a', 'Email12a@mail.com' from dual
;

commit;


select id, name, listagg('<'||username||'> '|| email, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
from customer group by id, name;
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME        USERNAME_EMAIL
1   Customer11  <User1a> Email1a@mail.com, <User1b> Email1b@mail.com, <User1c> Email1c@mail.com
2   Customer12  <User12a> Email12a@mail.com
```

Comment: Great! I'll give this a shot.  btw - it turns out the highest count of emails that I'm pulling per CustomerID is 5.  Doesn't mean there could be more later.  Thank you very much!

Comment: And I see what you're saying now and I should have clarified that also.  CustomerID does reside separately in the Customer table.  Orders stores the username and email; however, it does not have CustomerID.  argh  AND it is only joined to sales_trans by the usernameid. So, I had to join to sales to get the custID and join to the customer table.  c'est la vie. Yes, I would change if I could.

Comment: please kindly accept the answer if you think, your question was answered correctly - it might help others to find a proper answer. Thank you!